# Where is the problem in my logic for the Equal Stacks problem?

Tags: c++11, stack

For details about the problem, check this out - https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/equal-stacks/problem

We have three stacks of cylinders where each cylinder has the same diameter, but they may vary in height. You can change the height of a stack by removing and discarding its topmost cylinder any number of times.

We need to find the maximum possible height of the stacks such that all of the stacks are exactly the same height. This means we must remove zero or more cylinders from the top of zero or more of the three stacks until they're all the same height, then print the height. The removals must be performed in such a way as to maximize the height.

I implemented the stacks using three vectors, and found out the sum of heights of cylinders in each of the three stacks. Now, I implemented the pop() function on each stack repeatedly until either one of the stack becomes empty or the sum of heights of cylinders in each stack becomes equal.

//My function that returns the maximum height:

```
int equalStacks(vector<int> h1, vector<int> h2, vector<int> h3) 
{
     int s1 = h1.size(), s2 = h2.size(), s3 = h3.size(), sum1 = 0, 
     sum2 = 0, sum3 = 0;

     int i, j;
     for(i = 0; i < s1; i++)
        sum1 += h1[i];
     for(i = 0; i < s2; i++)
        sum2 += h2[i];
     for(i = 0; i < s3; i++)
        sum3 += h3[i];
     int height = 0;
     while(!h1.empty() && !h2.empty() && !h3.empty())
     {
         if(sum1 == sum2 && sum2 == sum3)
         {
             height = sum1;
             return height;
         }
         sum1 -= h1.back();
         sum2 -= h2.back();
         sum3 -= h2.back();

         h1.pop_back();
         h2.pop_back();
         h3.pop_back();
     }
     return height;

}
```

Sample input:

```
5 3 4
3 2 1 1 1
4 3 2
1 1 4 1
```

Expected output:

```
5
```

My program's output:

```
0
```

Comment: At each step, you are removing three cylinders simultaneously, one from each stack. Instead, you should remove them one by one, each time from the tallest stack (or at least, from one that is not the shortest).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you just remove the top of the stack of every stack in each iteration.

For example: You have three stacks, all having the base of a 5 unit tall object. Now only one of them also has one 1 unit tall object on top of the base; This will give you heights of 5 (1x5), 5 (1x5), and 6 (1x5 + 1x1).

In your algorithm you're firstly comparing the sums. "if ( 5 == 5 == 6) => FALSE ".

Then you take the object on top of every stack away. -> First stack: 0 units, Second stack: 0 units, third stack 1 unit.

You see the problem?

Igor mentioned it, but you first have to search for the largest stack and "work your way down".

Answer (score 0):

I found two things that need to be fixed.

1. Popping from the other way (Note that the input is given from TOP to BOTTOM)
2. Removing elements from all three stack at the same time does not gaurantee the optimal solution

For the first, I would reverse three vectors given at the beginning of the function. Although this is not very efficient, but this is for minimizing changes from your code. You should not erase the first element since it causes `O(N)` copies whereas `pop_back` is `O(1)`.

```cpp
    reverse(h1.begin(), h1.end());
    reverse(h2.begin(), h2.end());
    reverse(h3.begin(), h3.end());
```

For the second, here is a counterexample:

```
          bottom -> top
Stack 1 : 2 1
Stack 2 : 2
Stack 3 : 2
```

The solution should be 2, but it will return 0.

So we can change the strategy to pop only the longest stack at once. So I would change the while loop like:

```cpp
     while(!h1.empty() && !h2.empty() && !h3.empty())
     {
         if(sum1 == sum2 && sum2 == sum3)
         {
             height = sum1;
             return height;
         }

         if (sum1 >= sum2 && sum1 >= sum3)
         {
             sum1 -= h1.back();
             h1.pop_back();
         }
         else if (sum2 >= sum1 && sum2 >= sum3)
         {
             sum2 -= h2.back();
             h2.pop_back();
         }
         else
         {
             sum3 -= h3.back();
             h3.pop_back();
         }
     }
```

These changes would make the code a little bit slower, but does not change the time complexity. If you do not want to reverse the arrays, then you may think of keeping current indices for each vector rather than popping them actually.

Answer (score 0):

see i have made the same mistake previously hence now i know what to correct in above code below is the solution to above problem.

```
int equalStacks(vector<int> h1, vector<int> h2, vector<int> h3) {
stack<int> stk1;
stack<int> stk2;
stack<int> stk3;

int sum1=0,sum2=0,sum3=0;
for(int i=h1.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
    sum1=sum1+h1[i];
    stk1.push(sum1);
}
for(int i=h2.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
    sum2=sum2+h2[i];
    stk2.push(sum2);
}
for(int i=h3.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
    sum3=sum3+h3[i];
    stk3.push(sum3);
}
while(1){
    if(stk1.empty()||stk2.empty()||stk3.empty()){
        return 0;
    }
    if(stk1.top()==stk2.top() && stk1.top()==stk3.top()){
        return stk1.top();
    }
    else if(stk1.top()>=stk2.top()&&stk1.top()>=stk3.top()){
        stk1.pop();
    }
    else if(stk2.top()>=stk1.top()&&stk2.top()>=stk3.top()){
        stk2.pop();
    }
    else {
        stk3.pop();
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

def isEmpty(stk):
    if(stk==[]):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def assignTop(stk):
    if(isEmpty(stk)):
        return -1
    else:
        top=len(stk)-1
        return top

def s_sum(stk):
    if(isEmpty(stk)):
        return 0
    else:
        add=0
        for i in range(len(stk)):
            add+=stk[i]
        return add 
         
def equalStacks(h1, h2, h3):
    t1=s_sum(h1)
    t2=s_sum(h2)
    t3=s_sum(h3)
    
    top1=assignTop(h1)
    top2=assignTop(h2)
    top3=assignTop(h3)
   
    greatest= []
    greatest.append(t1)
    greatest.append(t2)
    greatest.append(t3)
    if(greatest[0]==greatest[1]==greatest[2]):
        return greatest [0]
                
    isEqual = False

    while not isEqual:
        
            
        g=greatest.index(max(greatest))
        print(greatest)
      
        if(g==0):
       
            greatest[0]=greatest[0]-h1.pop((len(h1)-1)-top1)
            top1=top1-1
            
        elif(g==1):
       
            
            greatest[1]=greatest[1]-h2.pop((len(h2)-1)-top2)
            top2=top2-1
            
        else:
           
            greatest[2]=greatest[2]-h3.pop((len(h3)-1)-top3)
            top3=top3-1
        if(greatest[0]==greatest[1]==greatest[2]):
            isEqual=True
        
    return greatest[0]    
    
    
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    first_multiple_input = input().rstrip().split()

    n1 = int(first_multiple_input[0])

    n2 = int(first_multiple_input[1])

    n3 = int(first_multiple_input[2])

    h1 = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    h2 = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    h3 = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    result = equalStacks(h1, h2, h3)

    fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```